# Short Circuit in SMO-created stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, smo

Due to a huge and hateful database that I'm not allowed to rationalise, I am forced to create a C# Datalayer generator for my app.  I'm pretty much done, using T4 to generate Model classes and Insight.Database repos but I needed to create my User Defined Table Types and Stored Procedures via Sql Management Objects.

What I'm interested in is, can I use a short-circuit parameter when creating via SMO?  What I want to replicate is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[cip_GetLicenses]
    @fldIndex int = null
AS
SELECT [fldIndex]
      ,[fldLicenceData]
  FROM [dbo].[tblLicences]
  WHERE (@fldIndex is NULL OR (fldIndex = @fldIndex))
```

I can construct the body of the sproc relatively easily with a string builder and some column iteration, but creating a parameter is done separately.

The StoredProcedureParameter Type does actually have a DefaultValue property but it's a string, and sadly setting it to " = null" simply throws exceptions at run time.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Why must you create the proc using `SMO`?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but your syntax is invalid: `WHERE (@fldIndex = NULL OR...` should become `WHERE (@fldIndex IS NULL OR...`

Comment: Try just `NULL` (no `=`). Failing that, though, I'm with Dan on this one: SMO gains you little to nothing here, except headaches. You could just execute the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement directly -- creating the parameter list is hardly more complicated than creating the body.

Comment: It might be just me, but I don't really understand what it is you are trying to do. Are you attempting to re-create the database structure from c#?

Comment: @DanGuzman I could just do it with T4 but since I don't _need_ to create a file, it seemed that SMO was the sensible way to go about it.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yeah, sorry, that's not active code, just an example I typed in a hurry.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I shall try that, thank you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  I need a datalayer for a C# application that will use this database.  I could spend a month writing every last bit by hand or half a day using T4 templates and SMO (if possible).  Which would you choose?

Comment: I'm still not following. A data layer for a c# application can be as easy as using entity framework (or any other ORM for that matter) - unless we are defining data layer differently.

Comment: I'm using Insight.Database.  Entity Framework is evil.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your answer is correct and works.  If you would like to add it as an answer, I will mark it accepted.